# sorting strings containing numbers and letters

Tags: c#, regex, sorting

I need to sort a list of scene numbers which are in fact a list of string and   contain numbers and letters.

this is the list

```
101-11
102-1
101-10
101-8
103-10
101-8A
101-9
103-4
103-4B
```

I've made following a Comparer

```
public class SceneComparer : IComparer
{
    private readonly Regex sceneRegEx = new Regex(@"(\D*)(\w*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        Scene sceneX = x as Scene;
        Scene sceneY = y as Scene;

        var firstSceneMatch = this.sceneRegEx.Match(sceneX.SceneNumber);

        var firstSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(firstSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
        var firstSceneAlpha = firstSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;

        var secondSceneMatch = this.sceneRegEx.Match(sceneY.SceneNumber);

        var secondSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(secondSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
        var secondSceneAlpha = secondSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;

        if (firstSceneNumeric < secondSceneNumeric)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (firstSceneNumeric > secondSceneNumeric)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return string.CompareOrdinal(firstSceneAlpha, secondSceneAlpha);            
    }
}
```

Which gives me following result

```
101-8
101-8A
101-9
102-1
103-4
103-4B
101-10
101-11
103-10
```

It looks like it's only sorting the first number before the dash and the alphanumeric but it doesn't sort the number after the dash to get following desired result.

```
101-8
101-8A
101-9
101-10
101-11
102-1    
103-4
103-4B
103-10
```

Any idea on how to get the desired result.

Comment: Split the string using "-" has the delimiter into a tuple<string, string> and then use LINQ to order by Item1 then Item2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `Split` the string and extract numbers in it to request sort on those fields.

```
// Assuming you have this...
List<string> list = new List<string>()
{
    "101-11",
    "102-1",
    "101-10",
    "101-8",
    "103-10",
    "101-8A",
    "101-9",
    "103-4",
    "103-4B"
};


// You could do this.
var result = list.Select(x=>
    {
        var splits = x.Split('-');
        return new 
        {
            first = int.Parse(splits[0]),
            second = int.Parse(Regex.Match(splits[1], @"\d+").Value),
            item =x

        };
    })
    .OrderBy(x=>x.first)
    .ThenBy(x=>x.second)
    .Select(x=>x.item)
    .ToList();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fAfoxf)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Use `Matches` instead of `Match`.

Also, correct your Regex as `\D` captures non-digit characters.

```
public class SceneComparer : IComparer
{
    private readonly Regex sceneRegEx = new Regex(@"(\d+)(\w+)?", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        Scene sceneX = x as Scene;
        Scene sceneY = y as Scene;

        var firstSceneMatches = this.sceneRegEx.Matches(sceneX.SceneNumber);
        var secondSceneMatches = this.sceneRegEx.Matches(sceneY.SceneNumber);

        var matchesCount = Math.Min(firstSceneMatches.Count, secondSceneMatches.Count);
        for (var i = 0; i < matchesCount; i++)
        {
            var firstSceneMatch = firstSceneMatches[i];
            var secondSceneMatch = secondSceneMatches[i];

            var firstSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(firstSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
            var secondSceneNumeric = Convert.ToInt32(secondSceneMatch.Groups[1].Value);
            if (firstSceneNumeric != secondSceneNumeric)
            {
                return firstSceneNumeric - secondSceneNumeric;
            }

            var firstSceneAlpha = firstSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;
            var secondSceneAlpha = secondSceneMatch.Groups[2].Value;
            if (firstSceneAlpha != secondSceneAlpha)
            {
                return string.CompareOrdinal(firstSceneAlpha, secondSceneAlpha);
            }
        }

        return firstSceneMatches.Count - secondSceneMatches.Count;
    }
}
```